# Some basic nginx rewriting

Tags: nginx

I'm new to Nginx rewriting. I know this is basic, but I'm constanty hitting the internal redirect cap of 10 when trying to do this.

Basically, I want domain.com/abcd.png to be domain.com/?v=abcd.png. This should only happen to files only directly under /, not any subdirectories under it.

Would appreciate any help anyone can provide me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+\.png) /?v=$1 permanent;
```